# How to include multiple app URLs in manifest for over-the-air installation

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, enterprise, ipa

Internally I have a 4-step process for testing (each is an environment): dev, build test, user acceptance testing and production.

Currently, I'm not using TestFlight and am having to create a manifest with the respective URL given each environment above. There's repetitive work.

Is there a way support multiple app URLs inside the manifest for over the air installation? Can I do it without TestFlight?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can inclide multiple .ipa links within a single .plist.  You just include multiple asset dictionaries in your plist.  We do this to offer a single "bundle" install of multiple internal apps. Here is an example of a plist with two apps (app1 and app2) make sure you update the `url`, `bundle-identifier`, and `title` for each app you include in the bundle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://server/app1.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.company.app1</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>subtitle</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>App description 1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>     
          <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://server/app2.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.company.app2</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>subtitle</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>App description 2</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Thanks but I may not have been clear but in my case there is a single app. So I want XCode to generate 4 builds out of it, each with their own app URL where they'd be downloadable from. I've tried just cloning the build and editing the manifest but for some reason that didn't work (over the air install errors out on "unable to download app" / "could not be installed at this time").

Comment: So do you have different build configs for each region? You said you cloned the build and then updated the plist? That would result in a single binary where each "region" would be the same build.  If that's the case, why not provide the same URL to all users?  OTA build errors typically mean that the URL you specified is wrong.  Also, if you update the URL make sure it is https, as apps can only be installed over https (not http) since iOS 7 I believe.